# OAuth (OAuth2) ASP.NET REST Web API (Self host - windows service) implementation

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have built a Restful Web API for my (android) mobile application, and now i am trying to secure the access to the API. I was reading for about a week on this topic and i got the whole spectrum - from those who say that is is impossible to secure a Restful API to those who say that Https (SSL) is enough.

Here I don't want to start a discussion about that.I have settled with OAuth or OAuth2 it doesn't matter(as far as I have read OAuth seems to be the better choice, but in the Microsoft tutorials they use OAuth 2, so here i am quite confused), and yes i know that they are completely different, but I am so frustrated of searching that I would accept either (I must admit that I expceted this to be much easier). As I said, I was searching for about a week, and all I got are concepts(a lot of them). You send some data  -magic start - usually username/password to the server, your data is being processed and you get a token back - magic stop-. On SO there are a lot of questions on this topic but most of the answers are unprecise (and unfortunately unusuable). For example I got this one [How to secure WEB API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775594/how-to-secure-an-asp-net-web-api/11782361#11782361), nice answers, but not really use of them, or this one [Implement Web API with OAuth and a Single Page Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980538/implement-web-api-with-oauth-and-a-single-page-application). I also got the examples from the Microsoft tutorials but there is a lot of overhead in the code and the part about OAuth isn't quite clear(which is unfortunate because the whole example should be about OAuth). I could post tons of links which claim to talk about this topic, but actually they are of no help.

What I am looking for is an simple, very very simple, example of an ASP.NET OAuth(2) implementation. It would be great if I just could use it with fiddler, provide an username/password in the header and with use of `grant_type: xxx` I get the token back(the permitted username/password can be hard coded inside the project, so no need for Entity framework implementation or any database on the backend). And it would also be great if someone could explain me how to use this token to authorize the user (I got it that I have to provide the Controller functions with the `[Authorize]` attribute, but how and where is this token-check being done ?). But please, don't post any theory about OAuth, I don't need that, here I am looking for the actual implementation of OAuth inside of Asp.Net Web Api

thanks

Comment: I am walking the same path, and now I'm stuck. Could you please share your code somewhere & save me from re-walking the same path as you did.

Comment: sorry I wasnt checking SO. Have you solved the issue ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is [detailed post](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) about adding the resource owner password credentials flow for your Web API project.

Comment: hi, I managed it by myself. Thanks for the answer, as I looked through it seems like there is some stuff which I could still use.

Answer (score 4):

**The most simple implementation** of OAuth2 in Web API project you can find here:

- [WebApiOAuth2 on GitHub](https://github.com/mholec/webapioauth2)

There are just two important files:

- `Startup.cs` (with settings)
- `AuthorizationServerProvider.cs` (authorization of users using oauth2)